# segmentation fault using OMP

Tags: stack, overflow, openmp

all! Typing from Italy
This little piece of code works if the matrix size is less then 800 and fails with a segmentation fault for higher sizes....
I have tried it with gcc 4.3.2 compiler in linux and macosx and VisualStudio compiler in windows.
Seemsthe problem is in the stack size..... how can I increase it ?
How can I solve the problem for bigger matrix sizes ?
The code works fine in serial put fails in parallel execution.
 Thanks.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define Nu 4000
int main() {
float A[Nu][Nu],B[Nu][Nu],C[Nu][Nu];
int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel
printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,i) shared(A,B,C) schedule(static)
for(j=0;j<Nu;j++){
for(i=0;i<Nu;i++){
//printf("Hello from thread %d, i,j %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),i,j );
A[i][j]=0;
B[i][j]=0;
C[i][j]=0;

}}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Default stack size in OpenMP is 4-8 MB. There's an environment variable called STACKSIZE you can change (for example to 16384, which is 16 MB). See chapter 5-5 of [this PDF](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/819-3694/819-3694.pdf).

Comment: The link is broken. It would also be good to know if there is a way to change OpenMP's behaviour from within the program, without messing with environmental variables.

Comment: FYI: at least on some systems, the gcc version of OpenMP seems to use 2MB as the default stack size for all the threads it launches.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have to allocate the matrix on the stack?

You could use the heap instead. For large amounts of memory, it can even be more efficient (the allocator implementation can use things such as anonymous mmap which allow the memory to be released back to the operating system when you deallocate it).

Comment: +1. @CesarB is right, objects of this size belong on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the stack size through the shell with

`'ulimit -s newstacksize'`

-- try 1000000

Comment: Unfortunately, the ulimit usually only affects the main thread, not OpenMP-created ones.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP threads are created with a stack size defined by the OMP_STACKSIZE environment variable (this is standard from OpenMP 3.0 on). If the environment variable is not present, the default stack size is implementation specific. You should probably rather be using the heap for such large allocations, but there can be legit reasons for wanting to change OpenMP threads' stack size.